# 32 Bit ODBC ( MYOB ) Runs under IIS / ASP.NET MVC on one Machine but not another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, odbc, myob

Spent a few hours on this. 2 seemingly identical machines with the same code , same operating system. I am trying to open a 32 bit ODBC connection ( MYOB ) that uses a .exe file to access it. It works on one machine fine - but not the other. I have looked at permissions , if 32 bit is allowed - but it just hangs when I try to open the connection - and the myobp.exe file does not start in process. It just hangs indefinietely.  No error message or anything.

any ideas why it is not working? I have given everyone full access to the exe and the exes directory - and all the code and machine is exactly the same. Firewall is completeley disabled even!

How can I get this ODBC driver to open?

Comment: Is it a 64 bit OS, and if so did you enable 32 bit applications in IIS? Have you checked the event viewer?

Comment: Thanks - event viewer found the issue.  Looks like the O/S toasted itself. sfc /scannow revealed lots of unfixable problems.